# TypeError while replacing string or int values in a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace, typeerror

I'm using the following code to replace string values in a column of the dataframe. The values are being replaced from the values in a dictionary. The code is as follows:

```
def ConvertColumnValuesToDict(df, colName):
    uniqueValues = df[colName].unique()
    colName2Num = {}
    num2ColName = {}
    count = 0
    for value in uniqueValues:
        colName2Num[str(value)] = str(count)
        num2ColName[str(count)] = str(value)
        count = count + 1

    return colName2Num, num2ColName

artifactId2Num, num2ArtifactId = ConvertColumnValuesToDict(Sessions, 'artifact_id')
Sessions['artifact_id'] = Sessions['artifact_id'].astype(str)
Sessions['artifact_id'].replace(artifactId2Num, inplace=True)
```

The final `replace` code raises the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-08fcc844456d> in <module>()
      1 # Sessions['artifact_id'] = Sessions['artifact_id'].astype(int)
----> 2 Sessions['artifact_id'].replace(artifactId2Num, inplace=True)

/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace, limit, regex, method, axis)
   3723 
   3724             return self.replace(to_replace, value, inplace=inplace,
-> 3725                                 limit=limit, regex=regex)
   3726         else:
   3727 

/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace, limit, regex, method, axis)
   3772                                                        dest_list=value,
   3773                                                        inplace=inplace,
-> 3774                                                        regex=regex)
   3775 
   3776                 else:  # [NA, ''] -> 0

/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in replace_list(self, src_list, dest_list, inplace, regex, mgr)
   3257             return block, val
   3258 
-> 3259         masks = [comp(s) for i, s in enumerate(src_list)]
   3260 
   3261         result_blocks = []

/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in comp(s)
   3245             if isnull(s):
   3246                 return isnull(values)
-> 3247             return _maybe_compare(values, getattr(s, 'asm8', s), operator.eq)
   3248 
   3249         def _cast_scalar(block, scalar):

/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in _maybe_compare(a, b, op)
   4617             type_names[1] = 'ndarray(dtype=%s)' % b.dtype
   4618 
-> 4619         raise TypeError("Cannot compare types %r and %r" % tuple(type_names))
   4620     return result
   4621 

TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'str'
```

**NOTE:** I am externally converting both, the key and the value in the dictionary to `str` in the function defined in the code. I tried another variation in which I didn't do an external conversion and let those values be `int`. That's when I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'int64'
```

Here's my sample dataset:

```
Session_id    artifact_id
    A              234
    A              123
    B              123
    B              678
```

The contents of the dictionary are as follows:

```
{'1':'234','2':'123','3':'678'}
```

I would like the final dataset to look like this:

```
Session_id    artifact_id
    A              1
    A              2
    B              2
    B              3
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It is completely unclear to me what you are trying to achieve, but trying to replace a column with a multi-item dictionary seems off. The sizes are also mismatching. However, if you make the replacement a dict comprehension, or append `.values` at least the TypeError goes away. It does not seem to have any value doing so though..

Comment: I'm not trying to replace a column with a multi-item dictionary. Sorry for not being clear. The column in the dataframe can have repeating values. In the dictionary, I have assigned an index to each unique entry in the column. I'm only trying to map the column entries with the dictionary entries.

Comment: Aha, sorry. You are right. I missed a detail. But it gets weirder: on my dataframe column I am quickly testing it on, which entails floats rather than integers, it works like a charm

Comment: Are you sure you are still doing the `Sessions['artifact_id'] = Sessions['artifact_id'].astype(str)` step in between?

Comment: @Uvar no, I am not. I'm doing `Sessions['artifact_id'] = Sessions['artifact_id'].astype(int)` instead.

Comment: Which I also see commented out in the error trace, BUT: could you try it as a string again? Like I said, I do not encounter any errors anymore from the original setup of the code :/

Comment: @Uvar I have been trying both, int and string, but to no avail. I tried running this on a smaller dataset and it does work. I don't have missing data too, so I'm not sure why it would work on a smaller dataset but not on the complete dataset.